# JSON.stringify return object Object

Tags: c#, json, stringify

```
item = {
    "obj": TabellaDettagliataVoceSingola
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Richieste/SalvaDatiPreventivo",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    success: function (response) {
    },
    complete: function (response) {
    },
    fail: function (response) {
    }
})
```

This is the code with a problem: json stringify return "object object" because the parameter that I pass to json stringify is an object. Then how can I do for return the records of the object instead "object object"?

Comment: Why not just `data: item` as it's already an object?

Comment: If I pass data: JSON.stringify(TabellaDettagliataVoceSingola)

The result is also this time object object

Comment: Don't stringify anything, it's not needed!

Comment: Ah, ok I didn't understand. But in my function that receive the data how type I must declarate? This is my function  "public bool SalvaDatiPreventivo(object[] obj) { return true; }"

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to stringify the object, just don't use `JSON.stringify`. so
try this :

```
item = {
    "obj": TabellaDettagliataVoceSingola
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Richieste/SalvaDatiPreventivo",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",
    data: item,
    success: function (response) {
    },
    complete: function (response) {
    },
    fail: function (response) {
    }
})
```

Comment: How type I must use in my function? 
This is the function

public bool SalvaDatiPreventivo(object[] obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

Comment: which function? sorry I could not understand?

Comment: Is it an action? or webmethod?

Comment: The function SalvaDatiPreventivo that I call trough the ajax call

Comment: a question: what is the `TabellaDettagliataVoceSingola`?

Answer (score -1):

when you recieve request at server side then parse the JSON

if you are using **c#** then try like this

```
ObjectVariable deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectVariable>(json);
```

If nodejs then try:

```
JSON.parse(object)
```